# Is it possible to add two step authentication to Lightswitch?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to add Duo security 2-step authentication to my Lightswitch application. Right now the HTML client only uses Forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do it but it is certainly possible to replace the default authentication providers in Lightswitch (Forms in your case) with your own custom provider. There's a very clear article at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2013/06/25/customizing-lightswitch-user-management.aspx on how to achieve that.

Your custom provider would then have to implement Duo. ASP.NET is a supported platform for Duo so it should work. But if it proves to be a problem (which I can see it might), you could break it into two chunks. Chunk one is an ASP.NET web application which uses Duo authentication (and doesn't really do anything else). The second chunk is your Lightswitch application, which is configured to use the ASP.NET application as its authentication provider.

There's a step-by-step guide to that process at http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/107/Integrating-LightSwitch-Into-An-ASPNET-Application-To-Provide-Single-Sign-On.aspx. It doesn't include Duo of course, but I'm presuming their documentation would be sufficient to integrate it into a standard ASP.NET application.

Phil